# Perform addition/subtraction within HQL query?

Tags: grails, hql

I am using grails 1.3.7.
I have a domain class Product like this:

```
class Product = {
   String name
   Float price
   Float discount = 0.0
}
```

I am performing search in my table using HQL (please dont ask why I'm not using `createCriteria` and `findAllBy`, my structure is much more detailed than just one Product domain).
I need to search between a particular maxPrice and a minPrice so I do:
`select p from Product p where p.price between :minPrice and :maxPrice`

I pass the require parameters and all works well. Now I need to change the HQL query so that it searches within the discounted price. 
How can I do something like:
`select p from Product p where p.price between :minPrice - p.discount and :maxPrice - p.discount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can do:
`select p from Product p where p.price - p.discount between :minPrice and :maxPrice`